# Can't use 'http://' for redirect url in google OAuth when my app is in production

Tags: google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am currently working on a project and I have implemented google OAuth with my app. It works fine when I'm working on my local machine (localhost:3000). But when I used the public IP from my AWS EC2 instance, Google API is giving an error "Invalid Redirect: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org).Invalid Redirect: must use a domain that is a valid top private domain."

Or when I use the public IPv4 DNS in my redirect URL, it's saying "Invalid Redirect: This app has a publishing status of "In production". URI must use https:// as the scheme." I want to keep my project in production. Here's an image of redirect URLs in google developer console.

[image: 1]

Comment: Change the HTTP:// to https you cant have none HTTPS urls in production.

Comment: I'll try using httpsand will let ypu know if there's an arror again. Thanks.

Comment: @SiddhantChaurasia did you get any fix ? I am facing same issue.